# Is printf length modifier %L standard (or future standard)?

Tags: c, printf, language-lawyer, c99, c11

Per [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) the length modifier %L is valid only for float types. But modern GNU compiler & library seems to accept it also for integers as synonym of %ll (long long). Is there a chance that cppreference mistakes on this? Or is %L for integers going to become standard in future?

Comment: `%L` is no length modifier, `L` is. the `%` is part of the conversion specification syntax.

Comment: `But modern GNU compiler & library seems to accept it also for integers as synonym of %ll (long long).`...source please?

Comment: @SouravGhosh-- From the [glibc manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Integer-Conversions.html#Integer-Conversions): "`L`, `ll`, `q` --  Specifies that the argument is a `long long int`...."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the latest C11 draft [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), §7.21.6.1 section 7:

> `L` -- Specifies that a following `a`, `A`, `e`, `E`, `f`, `F`, `g`, or `G` conversion specifier
>   applies to a `long double` argument.

So your source is correct, `L` as a *length modifier* is only defined for *floating point* conversions. I wouldn't expect this to change in future versions, as there's simply no need. Just use `l` and `ll` as appropriate.

Comment: Thank you. It was very tempting for me to use %L, it stands out visually and parsing is simpler. But let it be %ll.

Answer (score 3):

The valid length modifiers are listed [in §7.21.6.1 7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p7) of the C11 Standard.

The only mention of `L` as a length modifier in the Standard is for `long double` types:

> L
>       Specifies that a following a, A, e, E, f, F, g, or G conversion specifier applies to a long double argument.

Further, there is no mention of this in [§7.31 Future Library Directions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.31.11):

> 7.31.11 Input/output < stdio.h >
>
> - 1 Lowercase letters may be added to the conversion specifiers and
>     length modifiers in fprintf and fscanf. Other characters may be used
>     in extensions.
> - 2 The use of ungetc on a binary stream where the file position
>     indicator is zero prior to the call is an obsolescent feature.

And, the same use of `L` holds in [the POSIX Standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html): `L` is a length modifier to be used with `long double` types only.

Comment: `And, this is also not a length modifier mentioned in the POSIX Standard.`...am I missing something?

Comment: Thank you too.  . .

Comment: @SouravGhosh-- maybe I am missing something ;) I was just providing the detail that `L` is not only not standard in this usage in the ISO C sense, but is not even standard in the POSIX sense... but I should clarify my wording.